# allocate memory whose physical address >4GB in efi application?

Tags: memory-management, 64-bit, efi

I am wondering if it is possible to allocate the memory buffer whose "physical address" is beyond 4GB in efi application ?

Ex. There is 6GB DRAM installed on PC and efi application allocates 4KB buffer and its physical memory address is 0x100000000(=4GB)

Is it OK ?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: I have not tried it yet and just want to know if this is workable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a 32-bit platform this would not be possible, even if address extension technology permits more than 4GB to be installed. This is because of the requirement that all RAM is mapped 1:1 physical:virtual address.

On a 64-bit platform this should work just fine, as long as no silly platform-specific firmware bugs prevent it.

Some early x64 UEFI "bioses" forgot to actually map RAM >4GB - causing access violation errors, but on anything that was actually ever properly verified in anything other than BIOS compatibility mode (CSM), this will work fine.

Comment: Can I say that "a 64-bit platform" means (64-bit CPU) + (>4GB DRAM installed) + (64-bit efi shell/application) ? (I just want to know the requirements...Thx)

Comment: Well, I would consider any platform executing UEFI in 64-bit mode to be a 64-bit platform. Of course, if it doesn't have memory above 4GB it would be difficult to allocate memory above 4GB :)

Comment: Is there any function call for this purpose(allocate memory and return the physical address above 4GB) ? I will be grateful for any help you can provide...

Comment: Well, you can use the AllocateAddress flag to AllocatePages(), which lets you request a particular address to allocate.